# How to map a rectangle inside a scaled and rotated rectangle into the original bigger and unrotated rectangle

Tags: android, graphics2d

The situation is as follows:

I have a sampled image shown on screen, from which I can crop a portion of it after it has been rotated.

Once I've got the crop rectangle, I have to map it to the original image, which is unrotated and it's bigger.
Till now the scale factor hasn't been a problem.

This image shows more or less the situation(I know it's not showing the size difference):

[Image that helps explains the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbh6K.png)

So how can I get the mapped rectangle from Rect P to Rect Q?

Comment: do you use a Matrix when drawing rotated image?

Comment: yes, more specifically Matrix.postRotate()

Comment: so use one of Matrix.map*() method

Comment: I've already tried, but if I try to map the crop rectangle after the scaling, it always returns negative coordinates for some points of it.

Comment: hmm, what about invert()ed Matrix ?

Comment: Look this is what I get from Log after doing this:
`Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
matrix.mapRect(actualCropRect);`

ROTATION INITIAL RECTANGLE﹕ rect[1611.6001,1869.919][2257.6,2448.0]
ROTATION ROTATED RECTANGLE﹕ rect[1869.919,-2257.6][2448.0,-1611.6001]

Comment: but it is not the Mstrix you use for bitmap drawing, use that Matrix

Comment: The result is the same, it the matrix I use is indifferent if I only apply to it a rotation, it doesn't make reference to the plane where the rectangle is. It just looks at its coordinate points.

Comment: i think you need postRotate & postTranslate